# Why does it always outputs empty even when the database is not?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, db4o

```
private booolean dataSelected = false;
private void jDeleteActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    ObjectContainer db = Db4oEmbedded.openFile("barangay_data.db4o");
    try {
        Brgy_Data brgy = new Brgy_Data(idno, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null);
        ObjectSet result = db.queryByExample(brgy);
        if (result.isEmpty()) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Data is Empty", "Delete", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        } else if (dataSelected == false) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No Data Selected!", "Invalid Action", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        } else {
            Brgy_Data brgy1 = new Brgy_Data(null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null);
            brgy1 = (Brgy_Data) result.next();
            String msg = "Delete Data?\n";
            msg = msg + "First Name: " + brgy1.getFName() + "\n";
            msg = msg + "Last Name: " + brgy1.getLName() + "\n";
            int retval = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(this, msg, "Delete", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, javax.swing.JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
            if (retval == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
                db.delete(brgy1);
                javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Data Successfully Deleted", "Delete", javax.swing.JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    } finally {
        db.close();
    }
    clearTable();
    loadDataInfo();
    dataSelected = false;
}
```

So I select a row in jTable then delete. that then turns the boolean dataSelected to false. But somehow, the first condition always executes even though there are still multiple data in the database.

Edit: is there a method that can check if database is empty?

Comment: It seems you're looking for an element with a certain id. Are you sure such an element is still in the database?

Comment: Not looking, more like deleting data in jTable stored in db4o. I feel like result.isEmpty() is not the method that can read the size of all data stored in db4o.

Comment: Well, `db.queryByExample(brgy);` along with `Brgy_Data brgy = new Brgy_Data(idno, ...)` seems to be a lookup for an element with the given `idno`.

Comment: "I feel like result.isEmpty() is not the method that can read the size of all data stored in db4o." - Yes, that method is not meant to do that. It's purpose is to tell you whether your query returned anything, i.e. whether the returned `ObjectSet` is empty or not.

Comment: oh dang, didn't know that. is there a method that can check if the database is empty?

Comment: Well, you might be able to do a `queryByExample()` and pass the class or an instance with all fields being `null`. However, if you're only interested in knowing whether there's any record/object in the DB a `count` query would be better - if that's supported. To be honest, I don't know DB4O and it seems development has been abandoned for almost 10 years now so I doubt you'll find many experts who know it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (jTable.getRowCount() == 0) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Data is Empty", "Invalid Action", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
}
```

My classmate did this instead. Instead of checking the db4o, it just checks the tablerowcount since the table outputs all data from db4o anyways.